# How to see all the screen class engagements on firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I just integrated firebase to my android and ios app.

The dashboard has an engagement card where i can see the top 3 activities or viewcontrollers that the users engage in. The percentage only add up to 74%, and total engagement time is ~ 2 minutes while the average engagement time is 5 minutes.

As you can see from this image here[image]

But how do I see the rest of screen classes? I am pretty sure my app contains more than 3 classes, and I am quite sure my QA people go through other parts of the application.

Comment: Images would be usefull for people to understand

Comment: @UmarZaii Attached the dashboard view.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this, I'm wondering about the same thing

Comment: @Kris See my own answer. I was using an old version of firebase library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that i was using an old version of Firebase library. (9.8.0)

As you can see from this link here

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20170707

The automatic screen tracking is only added in version 11.0.0

After I included that version, everything worked.

I setup my iOS using cocoaPod so it was never an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The table generated by Screen Class is generated automatically by Firebase based on the most recent screens visited in your app.

You can [manually track](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#manually_track_screens) the desired screens in you app by having the *[setCurrentSreen](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setCurrentScreen(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))* method when the screen transition occurs. Those screens would appear when you will select ScreenName in the drop down.

Comment: But from what I understand, at least judging on the logs. It logs a screen event whenever a new activity is launched. Do i still need to do it manually? Doesnt https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#automatically_track_screens suggests I don't need to do anything?

Comment: @ZhenLiu Late answer, sorry, but what you're saying only holds true when one screen == one Activity. Which isn't true for everyone.